# windows store app crash due to timeout_expired

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

I have a WINRT windows phone 8.1 app published on the store. The store dashboard shows a very mysterious crash event which occurs frequently. Its details are as follows.

> Failure string name
>   EM_WATCHDOG_TIMEOUT_DEADA444_(MyAppName)_Timeout_expired:_event_type_=_SystemKeyPressed,_timeout_modifier_type_=_None,_server_task_currentState_=_Active,_targetState

I can understand that there is some sort of timeout expired in some calls. I can think of following places in app where that's likely

1) BackgroundUpload tasks - I am uploading files using background uploader

2) Web calls - App constantly makes web requests using HttpClient to a service

3) Suspension event - I am saving app persistence data while suspension

Has anyone faced similar crashes? Can anyone identify the exact cause for this?

(I know this question is quite vague but I can't provide more details)

Comment: I have a similar situation.

The dashboard has a message about the destruction. The stack trace is empty, no details no.

Comment: @user2784555 does your app use httpclient or background uploader or background downloader?

Comment: Ritesh Khichadia,  I`m have not httpclient and background uploader, only change lockscreen background (image in local storage).

Comment: Same here and it coincides pretty well with the switch to the Windows 10 Store. There is a whole thread on this on [the MSDN Forums](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/acc039ab-0163-4e40-90f7-4dd28135fe2e/wp81c-emwatchdogtimeoutdeada444?forum=wpdevelop) but sofar without any explanation.